# Is there an established method for bringing a White Box D&D character through a grand tour of D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, conversion

I'm running a tour of D&D sort of game, spending about two levels in each significant edition (I'm arbitrarily defining this as White box -> AD&D 1e -> 3.5 -> 4e -> 5e) I remember a few conversion texts to bring 2e characters into 3rd editon, but I was curious as to if anyone had come up with a guideline to bring a character all the way up to 5e for novelty sake.

Other than the obvious 'remake the character' solution, of course :)

Comment: Why do you exclude the only solution that has any chance of working? :-)

Comment: @DaleM Needed a decent Challenge Rating :) I would be amused and impressed to see someone navigate the idiosyncrasies of the various editions in some sort of systemic method.

Comment: I voted to close this as too broad because it feels like five decent questions all lumped into one that's going to be hard to answer well. I would be interested in seeing "ways to convert 0e->1e," "ways to convert 1e->2e," &c. each get their treatment. It gets OP their original answer when daisy-chaining each of the best answers together, and makes the individual questions' answers much more manageable and easier to vote on.

Comment: @nitsua60 unfortunately, I think that outside the broader context it's too easy to lose the game balance in the context of my current challenge. I could possibly break this down to a series of design intent questions. However, I think that would fundamentally change my question and I rather like the resources Adeptus found so I suppose I will start a series of questions therein.

Comment: @CyrusBufkin "Game balance" meant different things in different editions - largely because the expected foci of play changed from edition to edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no all-in-one conversion guide that I know of. However, Wizards has put out conversion guides for some editions as follows.

- I'm not aware of any White Box to AD&D conversion guide, but it should be easy to work out
- AD&D to 3.0 is detailed in this [Conversion Manual](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/conversionbook.zip)
- 3.0 to 3.5 is summarised in this [Update Guide](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/files/DnD35_Core_Books.zip)
- I'm not aware of any 3.x to 4 conversion guide
- This is a [conversion document](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_Conversions_1.0.pdf) for prior editions (1e-4e) to 5e

Note that none of the conversions are straightforward, "this-number-becomes-that-number" procedures. There is always judgement and "feel" required. You're not *quite* recreating the character each time, but you may as well be.

Comment: Although there's no White Box to AD&D conversion guide, there's almost nothing that needs to be done, so that's the easiest one to do on one's own.

Comment: It's a useful list! I'll probably end up having to implement my own solution and just give into the 'feel'y aspects, but these should be good guidelines to keep my estimates sane.

Answer (score 1):

There's already an answer for all the steps going forward from AD&D1e. Here's a quick guide for White Box to 1e.

Adjust experience total to the same fraction of the way through the level they are at. So, if the WB character had 22,000 experience, where 20,000 made them 6th level, and 7th level would be 40,000, they are (40,000-20,000)/2000 = 10% of the way through 6th level. If the 1e character class started 6th level at 25,000 and 7th was 50,000, 10% of the way through 6th level would be 25,000 + 2,500 = 27,500 on the 1e tables.

Adjust hit points, if hit dice are a different size. Do this by adjusting by the average difference: so if a WB character has 4d6 hit points, and the same character class in 1e would have 4d8, add 4 hit points. This is because the average roll on a d6 is 3.5, and the average on a d8 is 4.5, so there's a one point difference in the average.

Adjust bonuses and penalties for high and low characteristics to the 1e rules. Adjust combat skills, saving throws, weapon damage, thief skills, etc., etc., to the 1e rules. Adjust equipment effects, including magic items, to the 1e rules. Select appropriate weapon proficiencies (and non-weapon, if you use them), for the character's history.

Clerics and druids get to use the new spell tables. Magic-users and Illusionists have a problem in that there are a lot more spells, but the number of spells you can know at many Int scores is reduced. Toss out some spells to reduce yourself to a legal total, preferably ones you have not used much. If there are spells on the new lists that you want, ask your DM very nicely if you can discard some of the spells you know and replace them with new ones.

That's the main points; what have I missed?

Comment: So this looks like a great answer to the WB->1e part of the question... but OP asked for the "grand tour." I think that question's too broad and so have voted to put this question on hold. I hope that eventually we see questions for each of the steps in that "tour." I think this would be an excellent answer to the first of those future questions.